# Load all background-images at once with JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, browser

So right now I have a list with a bunch of Facilities. Each of these facilities has an `image` property which is simply just the name of it's image file. For example, `facility.image == 'YogisBarAndGrill'`. On pageload, I sent an array of strings (image names) via JSON and try to load all the images before the page and/or text is displayed.

Unfortunately, all my efforts are to no avail and the preloading doesn't work. Currently, the following is executed before `document.ready()`

```
(function() {
  var imagesPath, serviceURL, urlSegs;
  urlSegs = window.location.pathname.split("/");
  serviceURL = imagesPath = '';
  if (urlSegs.length === 2) {
    serviceURL = urlSegs[1] + '_images';
    imagesPath = urlSegs[1] === 'places' ? 'images/logos/' : 'images/categories/';
    $.getJSON(serviceURL, function(imageNames) {
      var i, _results;
      _results = [];
      for (i in imageNames) {
        if (i < imageNames.length) {
          _results.push((new Image()).src = imagesPath + imageNames[i] + '.png');
        }
      }
      return _results;
    });
  }
}).call(this);
```

The css for each list image looks like the following: `background-image: url('images/logos/YogisBarAndGrill.png')` or something similar.

Anyways - what I posted above doesn't work. No preloading is done. What I'm looking to achieve is having all images display at once **OR** even better would be to have the page display nothing at all until all images are done loading.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What if I'm on a slow 3G connection and I'd like to start reading the page before the 40 seconds it takes to load is up?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, that's fine. What's happening now is that the images display one by one as they're downloaded (I think each is a separate HTTP request... but I hope not). I'd like to just display all once the last one is downloaded - in that case.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the preloading “doesn’t work”, what do you mean? What do you expect to happen?

“Preloading” means “loading before you need”. If the HTML elements that have these background images are on the same page as the JavaScript you’re using, then the browser will be downloading them as soon as it’s parsed the CSS, which is unlikely to be noticeably long after the JavaScript has stopped running.

Comment: Ah, okay. So, I'm trying not to display any images until they're all downloaded then as they're all needed immediately. I guess preloading is the wrong word to use.

Comment: @Matt: ah! Gotcha. Further to your comment on your question, each image is indeed a separate HTTP request, because each HTTP request can only be made to one address, i.e. the address of each image. The only way to avoid that is to schmush all your images together into one image file on the server, then use that file as the background image on a fixed-size HTML element, and use background positioning to show the correct part of the image file. That’s called “spriting”.

Comment: @Matt: To answer your actual question, spriting is one way to only show images once they’re all downloaded. I’m not sure you’ve got any other options actually — in theory, JavaScript would be the way to go, but it looks like [jQuery’s attempt at detecting image loads](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) doesn’t work reliably, and if that doesn’t, I don’t hold much hope for other solutions.

Comment: @Matt: alternatively, if you can preload the images using your JavaScript technique on a page that the user is likely to have visited before this page, then they’ll probably be cached by the browser, and thus show up immediately when the user hits this page. Obviously it won’t work for users that come straight to this page.

Comment: There should really be a badge for adding three comments to your own answer within three minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by dynamically creating `<img>` elements for each image you want to load, let them complete their loading, then set `background-image` to the same urls. In the demo I use random images each run so they aren't cached.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Mp2cj/

#### Script:

```js
function loadImages() {

    var images = getImages( 5 ),
        imgs = [],
        loaded = 0;

    createImgs();

    var timer = window.setInterval( function () {
        if( loaded == images.length ) {
            window.clearInterval( timer );
            setImages();
        };
    }, 50 );

    function createImgs() {
        for( var index = 0; index < images.length; index++ ) {
            imgs.push( document.createElement( 'img' ) );
            imgs[index].onload = function () { loaded++; };
            imgs[index].src = images[index];
        };
    };

    function setImages() {
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll( '#container div' );

        for( var index = 0; index < divs.length; index++ ) {
            divs[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
            console.log( 'div' );            
        };

        document.getElementById( 'container' ).removeAttribute( 'class' );
        document.getElementById( 'loading' ).setAttribute( 'class', 'hide' );
    };

    function getImages( count ) {
        var images = [],
            url = 'http://placekitten.com/';

        for( var index = 0, width, height; index < count; index++ ) {
            width = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1000 - 500 + 1 ) ) + 500;
            height = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1000 - 500 + 1 ) ) + 500;
            images.push( url + width + '/' + height );
        };

        return images;
    };

};

loadImages();
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="loading">images loading...</div>
<div id="container" class="hide">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS:

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

#container div {
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;    
}​
```